# How to make img only as tall as its sibling in div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have a flexbox div with two children, an image and another element such as a

tag, is it possible to make it such that the image is only as tall as the natural height of the

tag (or whatever its sibling element is).

I often want this behaviour when displaying something like a multiline heading next to a logo, but the logo expands the parent div.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a flexbox container with two children, an image and another element like a `<p>` tag, you can make the image only as tall as its sibling element (or whatever its sibling is).

You can achieve this behavior in CSS by using the align-self property in combination with the align-items property on the flexbox container. Here's an example:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image">
    <p>Sibling Element</p>
</div>
```

and here CSS:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start; /* Align items to the top */
}

img {
    align-self: flex-start; /* The image will align to the top */
}
```

By doing this, the image will align to the top of the container, which means it will only have a height that matches its sibling element's height (in this case, the

tag).

This prevents the image from expanding the parent div. Using align-items: flex-start; on the container ensures that all elements align to the top, which is useful for multi-line headings next to a logo.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't doing the trick for me.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and CSS? @Sylith

Comment: <div class="flex-container>
   <p>Example Text</P
   <img src="./img">
</div>

With the css you shared.

Comment: I don't know why I received 2 negative votes when the question asker didn't provide their code here. I provided a standard solution that is typically used in normal circumstances."

Comment: I've tried your suggested solution using the code in my comment above (only those 3 elements in an index.html) and the css you provided and it doesn't produce the expected result.

I'm not sure that applying align-self to the img will have an effect on the maximum height it can be.